# ng-include lose data angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I'm new in angularjs and i have a problem trying to use ng-include inside a form.

HTML form:

```
<form method="post" id="formQuestion" name="formQuestion" ng-submit="sendForm()" novalidate ng-controller="questionValidation">
<ul>

    <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="'/templates/default/partials/_fields/f1.html'"></div>
    <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="'/templates/default/partials/_fields/f2.html'"></div>
```

f1 view partial

```
<li class="text-center">

<div>{{data | json}}</div>
```

Controller questionForm (parent)

```
.controller('questionForm', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.productTypeUrl = $routeParams.stringUrl;
    ...
```

Controller questionValidation (child)

```
.controller('questionValidation', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    alert($scope.$parent.data.productTypeUrl);
    $scope.isSubmit = false;
    ...
```

The alert into controller shows the correct value, but when i try to show this value into de view f1.html, the value doesn't show.

What i'm missing?

Thank u in advance.

Comment: Works fine for me. Something you haven't posted is probably causing an issue. http://plnkr.co/edit/8mh8uHJb8TEnumFiOV4q?p=preview

Comment: Controller 'questionForm' is not seen here, in ui-state?

Comment: I think that problem is that you are generating invalid html, you put `div` inside `ul`. So probably before angular starts, your browser fixing invalid html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that problem is that you are generating invalid html, you put `div` inside `ul`. So probably before angular starts, your browser fixing invalid html. It's similliar problem to own directive inside table, there are some solutions, first one, replace your `ul` and `li` tags with `div` or your `div` change to `li` another one, use a directive to replace those elements.

First try to replace this :

```
<form method="post" id="formQuestion" name="formQuestion" ng-submit="sendForm()" novalidate ng-controller="questionValidation">
<ul>

    <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="'/templates/default/partials/_fields/f1.html'"></div>
    <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="'/templates/default/partials/_fields/f2.html'"></div>
```

with this:

```
<form method="post" id="formQuestion" name="formQuestion" ng-submit="sendForm()" novalidate ng-controller="questionValidation">
<ul>

    <li class="text-center slide-animate" ng-include="'/templates/default/partials/_fields/f1.html'"></li>
    <li class="text-center slide-animate" ng-include="'/templates/default/partials/_fields/f2.html'"></li>
```

and f1 view:

```
<div>{{data | json}}</div>
```